# How to connect to adb via wifi?

Tags: android, wifi, adb

I'm try to connect my android with adb by Wifi. I do everything exactly, how i should:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.1.xxx:5555
```

Once for a lot of time it was working. But, when I unplugging phone, in 1 minute, devices are disconnect.
So, what should I do to everything works?

Comment: please add some more information such as error messages you may see, log files and perhaps some more information on the things you've tried to sort the problem out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Answer (score 0):

Drop the :5555 from adb connect perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I configured router and almost everything's working. Almost, because connection working without any problem, if phone is charging. When I unplugged it, connection is lost (I have Nexus 5 with android M preview 3).

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on "adb debugging" from Developer options. (Settings > system > Developer options)
2. From terminal, run the following `adb` command:

   ```
   adb connect 192.168.xx.xx:22
   ```